# Can SQLLite or SQLAlchemy directly work on a Pandas data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to use sql queries on pandas dataframe. 
But using where clause becomes confusing at times.

Since, I also have already build queries in SQL, I tried using SQL ALchemy but it first needs to create a connection with a RDBMS.Unfortunately my data is in CSV.

Please advise if I can use it on a dataframe directly and how.

Comment: Take a look at [pysqldf](https://pypi.org/project/pysqldf/). You can query your dataframe using SQL with this.

Comment: This should solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hi it seems that pandas support only reading SQLAlchemy results into Pandas dataframe.

One way would be creating a database and seeding CSV data to the database.

Other way would be to use queries on pandas dataframe. Pandas has built in query support for dataframes. You can take a look at this medium article for more info.

https://medium.com/jbennetcodes/how-to-rewrite-your-sql-queries-in-pandas-and-more-149d341fc53e

Comment: Yes, actually I am referring to the same document currently, but since I had over 200 attributes, just fishing for help.

Comment: Have you considered maybe loading data to NoSQL database like Mongo and then loading it to Pandas?

Comment: Not yet, was trying the direct approach.

Comment: So, I was referring to the article and I found airports[airports.amount.isin(['heliport', 'balloonport'])], now I want to multiply it with rate column; so I did airports[airports.amount.isin(['heliport', 'balloonport'])]*airports[airports.rate.isin(['heliport', 'balloonport'])]. Somehow, doesn't work